# how do i pass parameters from dropdown list to stored procedures

Tags: asp.net

I cannot pass a parameter from a dropdown list to a stored procedure.

Stored procedure :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Select_Newnews
    @NewsId varchar(4) 

    As
    select * from CommentsTbl where NewsId=@NewsId 
    RETURN
```

Code behind:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlParameter sp1 = new SqlParameter();
        c.com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewsId", NewsIdDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text);

        CommentGridView.DataSource = c.GetDataset("Select_Newnews");
        CommentGridView.DataBind();

          }
```

i m getting the error that the Procedure or function 'Select_Newnews' expects parameter '@NewsId', which was not supplied.

Please help me

Comment: What are you doing with the `sp1` variable ? Is there some code that we are not seeing here ? If you add the `sp1` parameter as-is to the Command's parameter collection, such an error would naturally result.

Answer (score 3):

This typically happens if you send `null` as parameter value. Make sure that the value is not `null` and it should work as expected. You can for instance try something like this:

```
object value = NewsIdDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text != null 
    ? NewsIdDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text 
    : DBNull.Value;
c.com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewsId", value);
```

That will properly send the parameter to the procedure if `NewsIdDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text` is a `null` value (by subsituting `null` with `DBNull.Value`.

Comment: Good catch, that's quite possible too. +1